# Code to Query two Joomla3 / Virtuemart3 tables and get field values

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla3.0

My SQL and php skills are very limited especially when it comes to Joomla. For at least a day now I am trying to write a query for two Joomla3 Virtuemart3 tables and get the datas but I cannot.
The tables are #__virtuemart_order_userinfos and #__virtuemart_orders common fields for both are the virtuemart_order_id the fields that I need, to start with, from the two tables are:

1. ## __virtuemart_order_userinfos :

   virtuemart_order_id
   company
   last_name
   first_name
2. ## __virtuemart_orders :

   virtuemart_order_id
   order_number
   order_total

The rest I can add, I think....

I probably need to have a JOIN for the two tables and select the correct fields based on virtuemart_order_id

Could you write for me the code for Joomla so I can add it to a php file I have created for Invoice and Receipt?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

please try the query below in joomla ..

$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select(array('a.virtuemart_order_id','a.order_total','a.order_number', 'b.company', 'b.last_name','b.first_name'))

->from($db->quoteName('#__virtuemart_orders', 'a'))

->join('Left', $db->quoteName('#__virtuemart_order_userinfos', 'b') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('a.virtuemart_order_id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('b.virtuemart_order_id') . ')');

$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadObjectList();

You can also apply conditions in where clause or can use order clause for ordering for the result. please check the link for further guidance - https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

Comment: I thank you very much for your answer. The script works ! ! but the 'echo $db->loadResult();' outputs only the value of virtuemart_order_id. The rest of the fields like company, last_name, first_name from virtuemart_order_userinfos and order_number, order_total from virtuemart_orders table are not displayed. How do I get those? Thanks ! ! !

Comment: You can use $db->loadObjectList(); or $db->loadAssocList(); in place of $db->loadResult();

Comment: Thanks again.... So if I have $resacc = $db->loadAssocList(); or $resobj = $db->loadObjectList(); at the end of my query code how do I echo let's say the last_name or first_name? When I have echo $resacc; or echo $resobj; it just displays Array ! ! ! How do I get field values from the row produced with the Join?

Comment: use print_f($resacc) instead of echo for result. and if you want individual value then use echo $resacc['last_name'] or echo $resobj->last_name.

Comment: How is it possible print_r ($resacc); prints all record fields : Array ( [0] => Array ( [virtuemart_order_id] => 5 [order_total] => 50.00000 [order_number] => 25 [company] => Internet Technology Solutions [last_name] => Χατσιούλης [first_name] => Γιώργος ) [1] => Array ( [virtuemart_order_id] => 6 [order_total] => 17.50000 [order_number] => JALA04 [company] => Internet Technology Solutions [last_name] => Hatsiulis [first_name] => George ) ) and printf ($resacc); prints : Array and echo $resacc['order_total']; NOTHING?????? I don't understand....

Comment: use echo statement inside the loop, use loop for the array